# MongoDB retain order of array for $in operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find a bunch of users in order using an array of ids. The array might look like this:

```
var array = [ '123', '42312124', '1231aoicali3' ];
```

This list is ordered, and I really want the users to appear in that order. I've noticed that reordering the same list does not reorder the documents I receive. Is there any way I can specify the order? The query I'm using right now is:

```
User.find({ '_id': { $in: array }})
```

I'm using NodeJS with Mongoose if that makes any difference.

Comment: You want to order the users and store it MongoDB?

Comment: No I want to query the users and retain the order of the IDs.

Comment: `I've noticed that reordering the same list does not reorder the documents I receive` - What do you mean by this?

Comment: This question has already been answered. I meant that no matter what the order is of the array, the documents returned will always be in the same order